# Error when building cordova App - Could not find property 'cdvCompileSdkVersion'

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, gradle

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/severindeutschmann/Meteor/pichapp/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle'
>     line: 48
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>
>   > Could not find property 'cdvCompileSdkVersion' on com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension_Decorated@54226e53.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

This happens when I try to build my app using Meteor build ......
There where several other issues before that, but searching github and google suggested editing build.gradle and build-extra.gradle - i fixed several issues on the way and tried several approaches but all of them end at this error message where i don't have any idea at how to fix it.

Would love if someone could help me, I'm stuck for hours on this now.

Answer (score 1):

replace `cdvCompileSdkVersion` by your own sdkVersion, my version is `21`, so as to `cdvBuildToolsVersion`.
There is an example:

`compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`